# Extending ListView onTouchListener

Tags: android, android-listview, ontouchlistener

I don't know if I simply couldn't find the class, but I need to do something more with the `TouchEvent` on a `ListView`.

I tried creating another `OnTouchListener` but by setting it on the `ListView` all the other functionalities are gone. I tried finding the old listener and then simply repass the touch event to it, but there is no `getOnTouchListener` method...

How would I accomplish this task?
Can I add another touch listener?
Can I intercept the event and repass it afterwards?

Thanks !

Comment: just made your own class that extends ListView and override onTouchEvent method after your implementation don't forget to call super.onTouchEvent

Comment: How can I find the class on the layout if the layout is a ListView not my implementation of ListView?

Comment: just change layout from <ListView/> to <your.package.your.ClazzMadeFromListView /> or use attribute class="your.package...." in ListView element http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: Thank you! should I just delete this question or maybe you could answer so I can mark as right?

Comment: leave it as is ... maybe it will help someone :)